# Remove additive transparency in ggplot2 geom_pointrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency

I am producing figures of effect sizes and associated confidence intervals such as this:

[image]

using ggplot2's geom_pointrange. I would like for the second point-line to be transparent but for the transparency not to be additive (i.e. just be one solid color rather than showing up as a darker line through the point).

I apply the custom colors with:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("#66CD0050","#66CD00"))
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: It would be nice if the plot was reproducible (ie please give some data and code to generate the plot)

Comment: I suspect this is going to be challenging using alpha transparency. The only way I can think of that grid would allow this is if you drew the point and line as a _single_ object, which suggests you'd have to construct it manually. It might be simpler to simply use two different colors (with no alpha transparency).

Comment: You are really asking for a workaround to sabotage the standard inking model adopted by R. As such, it is incumbent upon you to provide a date object to work with.

Comment: Just use the colour which corresponds to 31% ("50") opacity of #66CD00 on white, which is #cfefb0 according to the colour picker in Gimp - that will approximate what you are going for.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from thelatemail is spot on for this question.  Using the `scale_color_manual` call to define the colors will generate the image requested.  See the example below.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(effect_size = c(-0.1, -0.1),
                  lcl = c(-0.5, -0.2),
                  ucl = c(0.3, -0.01),
                  sla = c("SLA1", "SLA2"))

ggplot(dat) +
  theme_classic() +
  aes(x = sla, y = effect_size, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl, color = sla) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SLA1" = "#66CD00",
                                "SLA2" = "#cfefb0")) +
  coord_flip()

packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] ‘2.2.1.9000’
```

[image]